# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

With Jetpack Compose UI Tooling `1.2.0-rc01` and Compose Compiler `1.2.0`;

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.2.0"
    }
}
dependencies {
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.0-rc01"
    debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0" // being pulled in by another dependency
    debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview:1.2.0-alpha01" // also tried the latest version
}
```

The IDE cannot display the `@Preview`; it fails with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy$DisposeOnDetachedFromWindowOrReleasedFromPool.installFor(ViewCompositionStrategy.android.kt:97)
    ...
```

The actual cause is something else:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.R$id
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.classloading.loaders.DelegatingClassLoader.findClass(DelegatingClassLoader.kt:81)
    ...
```

How can I provide the missing [`androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.R$id`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/96f50779ed5822528f976074db6cd72975ea037a/customview/customview-poolingcontainer/src/main/res/values/ids.xml)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turned out when reading the sources, this needs the `customview-poolingcontainer`:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0"
```

Thought it was included in `customview`, but it's not. This makes the preview behave.

---

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/96f50779ed5822528f976074db6cd72975ea037a) it is being explained why it's like that:

> **PoolingContainer library**
> This adds an `androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer` artifact that is depended on by both `Compose` and `RecyclerView`, through which `AbstractComposeView` and `RecyclerView` discover each other and communicate about when the `Compose` view should dispose its composition.
> This mechanism is independent of both `Compose` and `RecyclerView`, and
> could be used for any recycling container or child with heavy resources
> that should be retained across recycling.
> Relnote: "Add a new PoolingContainer library that allows for listening
> to dispose events of a container that manages its children outside the View
> hierarchy.  This will later be added as a dependency of `Compose` and `RecyclerView`"
> Bug: 196371929

Comment: Annoying that this didn't fix the issue for me.