# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' Error while building project using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using jetpack compose in android project and I've got this error on making project

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Failed to transform customview-poolingcontainer-1.0.0.aar (androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
>   Could not find customview-poolingcontainer-1.0.0.aar (androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/customview/customview-poolingcontainer/1.0.0/customview-poolingcontainer-1.0.0.aar

Here is my dependencies:

```
    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha06"

    // Compose Compiler and test
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"
```

I've set `compileSdk 33` and `targetSdk 33` and also

```
buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.1'
    }
```

in my gradle.
And using these plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Before using BOM in gradle, I've tried version 1.3.1 for each compose dependencies which lead to Unresolved reference for material3 and ComponentActivity

Comment: Does the error still occur if you specifically add the custom view pooling container dependency? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807850/13258270

Comment: already used this answer. it won't work